# Exchanging AuthCode for Tokens multiple clients

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

Ok, so with one client I can get a authcode, exchange it for a token.  Then request resources using the token and successfully get them.  So I thought I'd try a second client and it always seems to want to authenticate against just the first client...if you can help me see what I've misconfigured it would be helpful.

Here's the relevant configuration:
From the OAuthServer:

```
@Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient("clientapp").secret(passwordEncoder.encode("123456"))
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "client_credentials", "authorization_code", "refresh_token")
                .authorities("read")
                .scopes("all")
                .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                .redirectUris("http://localhost:9081/login")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(7200)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(240000)
                .and()
                .withClient("client2").secret(passwordEncoder.encode("789123"))
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "client_credentials", "authorization_code", "refresh_token")
                .authorities("read")
                .scopes("all")
                .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                .redirectUris("http://localhost:9081/login")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(7200)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(240000);
    }
```

Here's how I get the auth_codes (I can use either user):

```
http://localhost:9081/oauth/authorize?client_id=client2&response_type=code&scope=all
```

Then once I have a an auth_code I exchange it for a token using `Postman` app and I get the following response.
[image]

And here's what I get when I use `clientapp` instead of `client2`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per OAuth 2.0 standards, Auth Code is issued to a specific client, in fact a particular user. Even can’t be shared with a different user using the same client. So the error is legal.

Comment: Yes this is true.  But shouldn't multiple clients be able to exchange authtokens at the authorization server?  In my case one client can exchange the auth token successfully but the second client cannot.